# can't pass data to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm learning codeigniter framework. I've managed to make login page work, now I'm trying to pass data from controller to my view. I'm getting errors I have looked and looked here and did as suggested still getting the errors/

**Model**

```
class Dashboard_Model  extends CI_Model{

    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getTasks(){

        $this->db->Select("COUNT(taskID) as totaltasks");
        $this->db->from('tasks');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('admin/dashboard_model');
    }

    public function index(){
        if(!$this->session->logged_in){
            redirect('user_login');
        }else{
            $data['title'] = $this->session->fullname. " | Dashboard";
            $this->load->view('admin/common/header',$data);


            $data['total'] = $this->dashboard_model->getTasks();

            $this->load->view('admin/dashboard',$data);
            $this->load->view('admin/common/footer');
        }

    }

}
```

**View**

```
 <h2 class="text-white"><span data-plugin="counterup"><?php echo $total?></span> <small><i class="mdi mdi-arrow-up text-success"></i></small></h2>
```

Error :

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: admin/dashboard.php
>
> Line Number: 40

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `$this->dashboard_model->getTasks();` retunrs array not string

Comment: $this->dashboard_model->getTasks() return the list of tasks. You need to do a count($this->dashboard_model->getTasks()) or i guess there is a count method on tasks collection.

Comment: @JagjeetSingh when I `echo $total['totaltasks']` I get undefined index totaltasks but when I var_dump($total)` I get `array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#22 (1) { ["totaltasks"]=> string(1) "4" } } `

Comment: @ThomasLefetz `getTasks()` return the number of tasks as a number

Comment: @user1 use count `count($total)`

Comment: @JagjeetSingh that will not give me 4 as total number of task but will give me array length which is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result()` This method returns the query result as an array of objects, or an empty array on failure update `getTasks` like below

```
public function getTasks(){

        $this->db->Select("COUNT(taskID) as totaltasks");
        $this->db->from('tasks');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result()[0]->totaltasks;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use row() to get single row instead of result() when you already know that you will get one row as a result

```
    public function getTasks(){

      $this->db->Select("COUNT(taskID) as totaltasks");
      $this->db->from('tasks');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->row()->totaltasks;
   }
```